# Need guidance on editing "Defending against XSS and SQL injection for a PHP beginner" for reopening or migrating to Programmers

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question, migration, reopen-closed

I recently asked the question "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18989544/defending-against-xss-and-sql-injection-for-a-php-beginner", which has been closed as too broad.

I'd like to edit the question so that it can be reopened and/or have it migrated to Programmers Stack Exchange.  What is the best way to go about doing this, and does it belong on programmers.se?

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/46716/what-should-every-programmer-know-about-web-development

Comment: "What are the most common attacks in simple web applications, and how do I defend against them?" -> https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Top_Ten_Project

Comment: `"What should I know"` type questions are fundamentally too broad for StackOverflow, and most likely Programmers as well. Did you go through all the links provided in the comments in depth?

Comment: I've narrowed the focus of the question.

Comment: @DragonLordtheFiery Now your question is a dupe of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: I wish there was a community FAQ about this, and I wish this was easier to understand for beginners...

Comment: A community FAQ for _what_, exactly?

Comment: @Oded: PHP security basics.

Comment: @DragonLordtheFiery Books can be written on the subject.  It's well beyond the scope of a single SO question.  If you really want to know all about it go buy a book about it, rather than asking on SO.

Comment: A community maintained PHP FAQ already exists: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/php/info

Comment: I'm working on a PHP security reference on my personal web site: http://www.fierydragonlord.com/reference/php-security.php. It is a work in progress but it will be based on the OWASP material and Stack Overflow answers.

Comment: Because the old Meta Stack Overflow is now [meta.se], I am voting to close this question as it is specific to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I agree that the topic of the question was too broad.  I don't think that Programmers.se will receive it any better.

You were given three links in the comments of your question on the main site.  Check those out.

You already know what terms to search for, and it appears that you're already researching it from your comment on the main site:

> I am aware of stuff like mysqli_real_escape_string(), but I want to
>   see examples on how to use it.

You're on the right track!  Now *find* some examples and read the explanations of how/why they work to stave off SQL injection.

If you get stuck, *then* come back to the main site, post code showing what's bugging you, and you'll get help.

The more specific the questions, the better.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance.  I'll come back and post another question if I run into problems.